# Set default value on selected ng-model and manage ng-change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-change

I cannot set the default value for my selected Item knowing that I'm supposed to get the default value from a json () use that selected value to show another form.

In my controller I have set the selected this way:

```
.controller('attributeFacetCtrl', function ($scope, tabsService, $location, contentService, attribute) {

    $scope.attribute = attribute;

    $scope.types = [{
        val: 'terms'
    }, {
        val: 'continuous'
    }];

    $scope.selected =  $scope.attribute.facet.data.type;

    $scope.isTerms = false;

    $scope.validateFrom = function() {

        var chk = $scope.selected.val;

        if (chk === 'terms') {
            $scope.isTerms = true;
        } else {
            $scope.isTerms = false;
        }
    };
})
```

the result of *$scope.attribute.facet.data.type="terms"*

And in my view I have this

```
 <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="wk-field-label">
                            <i class="icon-asterisk wk-prefield wk-mandatory"></i>
                            Type
                        </span>
                        </label>
                        <select class="wk-field-input" ng-model="selected"
                                ng-options="typeValue as typeValue.val for typeValue in types"
                                ng-change="validateFrom()"
                                required></select>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-if="isTerms" ng-repeat="orders in attribute.facet.data.order">
                        <div>
                            <label class="wk-field-label">
                                <i class="icon-asterisk wk-prefield wk-mandatory"></i>
                                Order
                                </span>
                            </label>
                    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What is the output of `console.log($scope.attribute.facet.data.type);`?

Comment: the console.log outpus : terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting `$scope.selected` to a string ("terms"), but when you're loading up `ng-options` it's loading it with objects that have a `val` property.

If you don't necessarily need `$scope.selected` to be an object, then you can change your `ng-options` to the following:

```
ng-options = "typeValue.val as typeValue.val for typeValue in types"
```

If you require `$scope.selected` to be an object with a `val` property then you will need to set its initial value appropriately and not set it to a string in order to set the default selection.

Comment: You are right having typeValue.val in my ng-options works

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to set the element by string, change your `select` element to the following:

```
<select 
  class="wk-field-input" 
  ng-model="selected"
  ng-options="typeValue as typeValue.val for typeValue in types"
  ng-change="validateFrom()"
  required
>
</select>
```

You can read more about how to use `as` here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Hope that helps!

Comment: I updated my question the _typeValue as_ does not change it, the default selected values is still empty on my view

Comment: Hard code `$scope.selected` as `{ val: 'terms' }` and then try hard code it as `terms` - one of those two have to work, but I'm positive that it was the original way I suggested it. Hard coding it will at least eliminate one of them :)